# Why is WebView in react native not opening?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, webview, wkwebview

using @react-native-community/react-native-webview package (v^8.1.2) to open a webview in a RN v0.61.5 project, no matter what I do, I cannot get the webview to display once the button is pressed. I have a button that opens it, but nothing happens. none of the error functions from the props executed, nothing.

here's the setup:

```
<Components.Button
    style={{ marginLeft: 15 }}
    text={"It's Copied. Continue"}
    type={'primary'}
    onPress={() => (
        <WebView
            style={{ flex: 0, height: height, width: width }}
            containerStyle={{ flex: 0, height: height, width: width }}
            automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={true}
            ref={(ref) => (this.webview = ref)}
            source={{ uri: 'https://connect.stripe.com/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=<....>&scope=read_write' }}
            originWhitelist={['https://*']}
            renderError={(error) => <View style={{ flex: 1 }}><Text>{error}</Text></View>}
            onError={syntheticEvent => {
                const { nativeEvent } = syntheticEvent;
                console.warn('WebView error: ', nativeEvent);
            }}
            onNavigatorStateChange={(event) => {
                if (event.url !== this.props.stripeUri) {
                    this.webview.stopLoading();
                    Linking.openURL(event.url);
                }
            }}
        />
    )}
/>
```

As you can see, the things ive tried:

- setting `flex:0` with a specified height, width
- whitelisting uri with wildcard
- setting various error props
- re-running `pod install`

No errors register in console, no new error view renders.

the last time I looked at this code it was working fine, not sure what happened. Any thoughts?

EDIT: link to snack: https://snack.expo.io/uTkqnGbny

Comment: remove flex:0 in stype

Comment: @MuhammadNuman changes nothing. `flex: 1, flex: 0`, and not setting flex all exhibit the behavior mentioned above

Comment: you can debug code by add backgroundColor in style if there is the problem in height or flex

Comment: @MuhammadNuman explain how that would help when nothing is displaying whatsoever

Comment: can you give me your git demo code so I can fix your problem

Comment: https://snack.expo.io/uTkqnGbny

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is my **snack** code

https://snack.expo.io/sfDcMtiIR

Code:

```
import * as React from "react";
import {
  Text,
  View,
  StyleSheet,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Linking,
  Dimensions,
} from "react-native";
import { WebView } from "react-native-webview";
import Constants from "expo-constants";
const { height, width } = Dimensions.get("window");
const testURI = "https://google.com";

export default function App() {
  const [isShowWebView, setIsShowWebView] = React.useState(false);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <TouchableOpacity
        style={{
          height: 50,
          width: "100%",
          borderRadius: 50,
          justifyContent:"center",
          alignItems:"center"
        }}
        onPress={() => setIsShowWebView(!isShowWebView)} >
        <Text>Open Webview</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>

      {isShowWebView && (
        <WebView
          style={{ height: height, width: width }}
          containerStyle={{ height: height, width: width }}
          ref={(ref) => (this.webview = ref)}
          source={{ uri: testURI }}
          renderError={(error) => (
            <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
              <Text>{error}</Text>
            </View>
          )}
          onError={(syntheticEvent) => {
            const { nativeEvent } = syntheticEvent;
            console.warn("WebView error: ", nativeEvent);
          }}
          onNavigatorStateChange={(event) => {
            if (event.url !== testURI) {
              this.webview.stopLoading();
              Linking.openURL(event.url);
            }
          }}
        />
      )}
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: "#ecf0f1",
    padding: 8,
  },
});
```

Comment: the point is to open the webview when the button is pressed. putting the webview as child of the touchable opacity, display the webview as a button. which is not the desired effect. the goal is to open the web view on press.

Comment: Hi, my webview isnt working when i replace my local ip address with my AWS EC2 ipV4

Answer (score 1):

I think i know what you want.

I createfd a state var to we toggle the web view using the button.

Please try my snack (using Android or iOS).

https://snack.expo.io/lYItc9ACk

Code:

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, Linking, Dimensions } from 'react-native';
import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview'
import Constants from 'expo-constants';
const {height, width} = Dimensions.get('window');
const testURI = "https://google.com";

export default function App() {
  const [showWebView, setShowWebview] = React.useState(false);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <TouchableOpacity
        style={{width:'90%', height: 50, backgroundColor:'#333', borderRadius: 50, alignSelf: 'center'}} 
        onPress={() => setShowWebview(!showWebView)}
      >
      </TouchableOpacity>

      { !!showWebView &&
        <WebView
          style={{ flex: 1, height: height, width: width }}
          containerStyle={{ flex: 1, height: height, width: width }}
          ref={(ref) => (this.webview = ref)}
          source={{ uri: testURI }}
          renderError={(error) => (
            <View style={{ flex: 1 }}><Text>{error}</Text></View>
          )}
          onError={syntheticEvent => {
            const { nativeEvent } = syntheticEvent;
            console.warn('WebView error: ', nativeEvent);
          }}
          onNavigatorStateChange={(event) => {
            if (event.url !== testURI) {
              this.webview.stopLoading();
              Linking.openURL(event.url);
            }
          }}
        />
      }
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the entire styling and just go with source: uri

Comment: you're using an older version of rn-webview, update to the latest version (9.1.1 i think) and see if it solves the issue

Comment: did not fix issue